# Rewarded Videos - Time Left Counter

Tags: android, video, time, reward

I would like to ask a question about rewarded videos in Android. I have set the rewarded videos to show once per hour, which means every user can watch one video per one hour.

My question is, what is the USER? What is google tracking actually? Is it the device, IP, google play account or anything else?

This is the reason why I need this info:

I like to set a counter that will show the players how much time has left until the next rewarded video.

Scenario 1:
Player logs in account A. It watches the video and after 15 minutes switches to account B on the same device. Since accounts are not related to google (internal game accounts) I guess the player wouldn't be able to watch the video in the next 45 minutes even if it is another account.

Scenario 2:
Player logs in account A. It watches the video and after 15 minutes switches the device (logs in account A on another device). Player shouldn't be able to watch the video in the next 45 minutes (because it is the same game account), but can it watch the video on the another device with different google play account and another IP let we say?

My first point was to relate the time left with the game account, but since I thought of these two scenarios, I have doubts about it. I would like to know this to set the counter properly.